# hadoop custom writable not producing the expected output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a set of inputs to reducer from the mapper:

```
(1939, [121, 79, 83, 28]) 
(1980, [0, 211, −113])
```

I want to get output as following:

```
1939 max:121 min:28 avg: 77.75
```

I can get it if i don't use a custom writable as following in my reducer class:

```
public static class MaxTemperatureReducer
      extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {
          Text yearlyValue = new Text();
      @Override
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
          Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            int CounterForAvg = 0;
            int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            float avg;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                int currentValue = val.get();
                sum += currentValue;
                CounterForAvg++;
                minValue = Math.min(minValue, currentValue);
                maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, currentValue);
            }
            avg = sum / CounterForAvg;
            String requiredValue = "max temp:"+maxValue + "\t" +"avg temp: "+ avg + "\t"+ "min temp: " +minValue;
            yearlyValue.set(requiredValue);
            context.write(key, yearlyValue);
      }
    }
```

However using a customwritable class is producing the following:

```
1939 121
1939 79
1939 83
1939 28
1980 0
1980 211
1980 -113
```

Here is how i have implemented the custom class and reducer. I sent the iterables to the custom class and performed the computation there. I can't figure out what i am doing wrong here. I have 0 exp in java.

```
public  class CompositeWritable implements Writable {

         String data = "";

        public CompositeWritable() {

        }

        public CompositeWritable(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            data = WritableUtils.readString(in);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
             WritableUtils.writeString(out, data);
        }

        public void merge(Iterable<IntWritable> values) {
             int sum = 0;
             int CounterForAvg = 0;
             int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
             int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
             float avg;
             for (IntWritable val : values) {
                    int currentValue = val.get();
                    sum += currentValue;
                    CounterForAvg++;
                    minValue = Math.min(minValue, currentValue);
                    maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, currentValue);
                }
             avg = sum / CounterForAvg;
             data = "max temp:"+maxValue + "\t" +"avg temp: "+ avg + "\t"+ "min temp: " +minValue;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return data;
        }

    }
```

---

```
public static class MaxTemperatureReducer
      extends Reducer<Text, CompositeWritable,Text, Text> {
            CompositeWritable out;
            Text textYearlyValue = new Text();

      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
          Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
             out.merge(values);
            String requiredOutput = out.toString();
            textYearlyValue.set(requiredOutput);
            context.write(key,textYearlyValue );
      }
    }
```

My job configuration is as follows:

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), "MaxAvgMinTemp");
            job.setJarByClass(this.getClass());

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

            job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
            job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

            return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: If you'd implemented this correctly, `out.merge(values);` should throw a nullpointerexception because `out` is never initialized

Comment: @cricket_007 it does not throw a nullpointerexception the reducer runs successfully.

Comment: Okay, `setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);`... This won't work if you're trying to output Text

Comment: Plus, your `CompositeWritable` is almost the exact same thing as `Text`, so it's not clear why you need it

Comment: @cricket_007, the same configuration is working if i don't use the CompositeWritable. Do i need to set the output value class to CompositeWritable. I was trying to get a custom writable class to write 3 dimensional value to specific date

Comment: You don't have a three dimensional value, though. You have a single string. The output value needs to be the output of the reducer (which you've defined as Text, not a Int or Custom one)... If you want the mapper to output a different value type, you need to call the respective method for setting that

Comment: sorry i meant to calculate max, min and avg and put it to the output from the reducer by utilizing the CompositeWritable. @cricket_007

Comment: I understand that, but you're not "composing" any more than a single string of data, which is what `Text` already does

Comment: @cricket_007 i got it, but shouldn't the call for merge help me concat the values and return that value for a specific key? For example 1988 112 
1988 123 , should it return 1988 max: 123 min:112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shouldn't the call for merge help me concat the values

Sure, but you're not using it correctly. `out` is never initialized.

```
  CompositeWritable out; // null here
  Text textYearlyValue = new Text();

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
      Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         out.merge(values); // still null, should throw an exception
```

---

If you want to output a single line of a string, you can just use a `Text` object. Your `merge(Iterable<IntWritable> values)` method can go anywhere, it does not have to be in an entirely separate class to return you a Writable object.

---

But anyway, if the exercise is to learn how to implement a custom writable, then here you go.

Things to note:

1. If you want to "compose" more than one field, then you should declare them
2. `readFields` and `write` need to be in the same order
3. `toString` determines what you seen in the reducer output when using the `TextOutputFormat` (the default)
4. `equals` and `hashCode` are added for completeness (ideally you would implement `WritableComparable`, but that really only matter for keys, not so much values)
5. To be similar to other Writables, I renamed your `merge` method to `set`.

You can expect the output of below to look like

```
1939    MinMaxAvgWritable{min=28, max=121, avg=77.75}
1980    MinMaxAvgWritable{min=-113, max=211, avg=32.67}
```

```
public class MinMaxAvgWritable implements Writable {

    private int min, max;
    private double avg;

    private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MinMaxAvgWritable{" +
                "min=" + min +
                ", max=" + max +
                ", avg=" + df.format(avg) +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MinMaxAvgWritable that = (MinMaxAvgWritable) o;
        return min == that.min &&
                max == that.max &&
                avg == that.avg;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(min, max, avg);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {
        dataOutput.writeInt(min);
        dataOutput.writeInt(max);
        dataOutput.writeDouble(avg);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput dataInput) throws IOException {
        this.min = dataInput.readInt();
        this.max = dataInput.readInt();
        this.avg = dataInput.readDouble();
    }

    public void set(int min, int max, double avg) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.avg = avg;
    }

    public void set(Iterable<IntWritable> values) {
        this.min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        this.max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (IntWritable iw : values) {
            int i = iw.get();
            if (i < this.min) this.min = i;
            if (i > max) this.max = i;
            sum += i;
            count++;
        }

        this.avg = count < 1 ? sum : (sum / (1.0*count));
    }
}
```

With this, the reducer is very simple

```
public class CompositeReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, MinMaxAvgWritable> {

    private final MinMaxAvgWritable output = new MinMaxAvgWritable();

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // This 'set/merge' method could just as easily be defined here, and return a String to be set on a Text object
        output.set(values);  
        context.write(key, output);
    }
}
```

And the job is setup like so

```
    // outputs for mapper and reducer
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

    // setup mapper
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);  // Replace with your mapper
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // setup reducer
    job.setReducerClass(CompositeReducer.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(MinMaxAvgWritable.class); // notice custom writable

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: Note: This computation requires much less code in Spark, Pig, or Hive

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, i did study the article given by yahoo however, now i get the gist of what that article meant.

Comment: I'm not sure which article you're referring to